# regex not replacing word starting with "." or ending with "+" like ".NET" or "C++"

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace `'.net'` in `'i like .net'` with `.NET`. Expected output: `'i like .NET'.`

Also `'c++'` in `'i like c++'` with `Cpp`. Expected output: `'i like Cpp'.`

There are more cases with special characters like 'c++'

```
import re

regex_match = re.compile(r'\bnet\b')
print(regex_match.sub('NET', 'I like .net'))
# output I like .NET Which works but I need boundary match also.

regex_match = re.compile(r'\b.net\b')
print(regex_match.sub('NET', 'I like .net'))
# output I like .net

regex_match = re.compile(r'\b\.net\b')
print(regex_match.sub('NET', 'I like .net'))
# output I like .net

regex_match = re.compile(r'\b' + re.escape('.net') + '\b')
print(regex_match.sub('NET', 'I like .net'))
# output I like .net

regex_match = re.compile(r'\b' + re.escape('.net') + '\b')
print(regex_match.sub('NET', 'I like \.net'))
# output I like \.net

print(re.sub(r'\b' + re.escape('.net') + '\b', '.NET', 'I like .net'))
# output I like .net

regex_match = re.compile(r'\b' + re.escape('.net') + '\b')
print(regex_match.sub('NET', re.escape('I like .net')))
# output I\ like\ \.net
```

UPDATE:

```
regex_match = re.compile(r'\b' + re.escape('c++') + '\b')
print(regex_match.sub('cpp', 'I like c++'))
# output `I like c++` expected `I like cpp`
```

I went through a lot of stackoverflow questions on regex replace. and everywhere its suggested escape '.', which i tried as you can see above. still its not working. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It is a common question. `\b` before `.`  requires a word char before `.`. You have none.

Comment: You should escape the dot, otherwise it matches any character, i.e. `.net` will match `anet`, which `\.net` won't. You will want to escape characters when they have a special meaning but you just want to represent the character itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `\b` before `.` requires a word char before `.`. A `\b\.` will match a `.` in `ASP.NET`, but not in `In .NET`.

If you want to match whole words regardless of the characters at the start/end of the search words, the best bet is to use lookarounds:

```
import re
regex_match = re.compile(r'(?<!\w){}(?!\w)'.format(re.escape('.net')))
print(regex_match.sub('NET', 'I like .net, not  my.net.'))
# => I like NET, not  my.net.
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/j8cADT). It will still work the same if you use `net` instead of `.net` (see [another Python demo](https://ideone.com/xjKSVD)).

Here, `(?<!\w)` will require a non-word char or start of string immediately before the search word, and `(?!\w)` will require a non-word char or end of string immediately after the search word.

Comment: seems like this can handle most cases. Thanks a lot for this. if it works out for all my cases it will be awesome. I have words with no special character also. I was looking for a solution that can work across all conditions.

Comment: @VikashSingh It will handle all the cases, be it `.net`, `net.` or `net`.

Comment: Won't it replace `'I like my..net'` into `I like my..NET` ?

Comment: @anubhava Of course it will because `.net` in `...net` is a whole word, i.e. `.net` is not preceded with a word char.

Comment: For that matter `.net` is whole word even in `I like.net`

Comment: @anubhava fair point. but that is as expected. Think of it like when someone writes `'I like my..net'` they mean `.net` as a term. but not in `i like net` or 'i like inet` or 'my .network` or `i.net` then the context wont be `.net`. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @anubhava fair point. your example is more semantic, Human interpretation of the sentence will reveal `I like.net` to have `.net` keyword. But something like `i.net` could be a different term and not `.net` at all. that's why the question was bothering me for a while.

Answer (score 5):

Don't place `\b` (word boundary) before dot since dot is not a word character.

You can use:

```
>>> regex_match = re.compile(r'\.net\b')
>>> print(regex_match.sub('.NET', 'I like .net'))
I like .NET
```

---

**EDIT:**

Based on your comments you can probably use this regex:

```
>>> print(re.sub(r'(^|\s)\.net(?=\s|$)', r'\1.NET', 'I like .net'))
I like .NET

>>> print(re.sub(r'(^|\s)\.net(?=\s|$)', r'\1.NET', 'I like.net'))
I like.net
```

Comment: fair point. but it doesn't solve the case for `print(regex_match.sub('.NET', 'I like my.net'))` will output `I like my.NET` Which it seems can't be solved.

Comment: @VikashSingh then what about `r'\s+\.net\b'`, which will match only when ".net" follows a whitespace.

Comment: @anubhava yes. That's the idea. Only a mention of `.net` should be replaced. @WiktorStribiżew looking..

Comment: @Zinki Then it won't match at the start of a string.

Comment: issue with `\s+` means the word has to have a space right before it. and it does not match the start of the sentence. so i can do something like `[^\s]\.net`, something of that sort.

Comment: @anubhava No, it won't work because OP already commented: *issue with `\s+` means the word has to have a space right before it*.

Comment: @Zinki See my answer.

Comment: @Zinki: Yes, that's what I have in edited answer and I believe that should work for OP.

Comment: @anubhava thanks for all the help :) My upvote for the effort and all the cases your code handles. But what Wiktor did makes more sense for my use case. :)